# Blurry Text in Modal When Centering With translate(-50%,-50%);

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am experiencing blurry text (in chrome) in a modal which is centered via `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);`

The modal can not have its width specified explicitly in pixels.

Here is the current css for the modal div:

```
#emod 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50.1%,-50.2%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50.1%,-50.2%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%); 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 100px 100px 100px;
    background-color:White;
    overflow:auto;
    */
}
```

i've read all of the various existing questions and suggestions, and I have tried all of the common suggestions for fixing this, each individually and in some combos, including:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50.1%,-50.1%)
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0); /*this one causes div to not be centered anymore, but works*/
```

Any ideas how i can overcome this?  I've read about a javascript fix that rounds decimal pixels to even numbers, but couldnt find any details on how to implement it. I'd prefer a css solution, but im cool with a js workaround...

I also use jQuery in this project so a jQuery solution would also work.

Comment: Check the `height` and/or `max-height` values of your modal in the inspector computed tab. It seems when those values are not integer, then the blurry effect can appear (it was the case for me). This article explains this well: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-fix-blurry-elements-that-have-position-fixed-934c707b4e19

Answer (score 0):

Try adding font smoothing. This has worked for me before.

-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;